# Correct use Javascript DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I trying use the `Javascript DOM`. I need get a information (data-content), searching by `class`.

The html of website is:

```
<li class="item info-icon info-icon-phone">
   <strong itemprop="telephone" class="phone-place js-expansible-text js-phone-tracker display-phone_ad" data-content="(19) 3879-1066 / (19) 3879-1066" data-style_class="clickable" data-place_id="76588JTY">(19) 3879-1066 / (19) 3879-1066</strong>
</li>
```

My code doesn't works:

```
var script = document.getElementsByClass('phone-place js-expansible-text js-phone-tracker display-phone_ad');
```

Comment: Did u mean `getElementsByClassName` ?

Comment: Why is this tagged as jquery?

Comment: `var script = document.getElementsByClassName('phone-place js-expansible-text js-phone-tracker display-phone_ad').innerHTML` the return is null

Comment: @ReneSá It's not entirely clear from your question whether you're actually wanting to get the value of the `data-content` attribute or the text node of the element (the `innerHTML`)

Comment: @ReneSá then I believe my answer below should give you what you need. Using the `getAttribute` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve element attributes using the [getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) method.

In this instance you could use the following to get the data-content attributes:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('phone-place js-expansible-text js-phone-tracker display-phone_ad');
var dataContent = elements[0].getAttribute('data-content');
```

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array of matching elements, you could replace this with `getElementByClassName` with returns a single element, this is preferable if you're only expecting one element. In my example you will see you need to reference the first element in the array `elements[0]` before calling getAttribute()

Instead with getElementByClassName do the following:

```
var element = document.getElementByClassName('phone-place js-expansible-text js-phone-tracker display-phone_ad');
var dataContent = element.getAttribute('data-content');
```

[A quick bin to show this in action](https://jsbin.com/godifituga/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: This code show the "innerHTML" too. Try change the innerHTML and see the result.

Comment: @ReneSá That's because in your provided example the value of innerHTML and data-content attribute are the same. It's not 100% clear from your question what you are trying to do, can you clarify? If you need to get just the innerHTML use `elements[0].innerHTML`

Comment: What is `getElementByClassName`? To retrieve a data attribute, it's preferable to use `dataset.content`.

Comment: @torazaburo i'm not sure what you mean. I think you're referring to a completely different language.

Comment: Look it up, check it out. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Comment: @torazaburo sorry i was confused about your question re: getElementByClassName that's because that's how the OP wants to access the element, as a side point, it's worth noting HTMLElement dataset isn't available before IE11.

Answer (score 2):

```
var script = document.getElementsByClassName('phone-place js-expansible-text js-phone-tracker display-phone_ad');
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp

Comment: `var script = document.getElementsByClassName('phone-place js-expansible-text js-phone-tracker display-phone_ad').innerHTML` the return is null

Comment: And this solves the problem (which is what?) how?

Comment: `GetElementsByClass` is incorrect syntax. It's supposed to be `GetElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 2):

I believe the function you are looking for is getElementsByClassName.
[What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-does-getelementsbyclassname-return)